# If I repeatedly roll two fair six-sided dice, what is the probability that I will roll three 2s before I roll seven 6s?

Tags: probability, dice

I would like to understand the math behind a basic racing game.

2d6 are rolled and the result advances the corresponding horse along the track (a roll of '7' would advance the #7 Horse).  To win the race, the #7 Horse needs to advance a total of 8 times - while the # 2 and #12 horses only need to advance three times.

How do I calculate the probability that the #2 horse will win the race?

[NOTE:  The 3/11 Horses must advance 4 times, the 4/10: 5 times, the 5/9: 6 times, 6/8 horses: 7 times.  These do not need to be included in the answer, but are included for completeness.]

I understand the basic probability of rolling two fair six-sided dice.

Comment: Just answering your title as a hint: You need to add the probability of your event happening given $n$ rolls, then you need to sum the result over all $n$, I believe. A very interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the question in the title.

The probability that you throw 3 twos before 7 sixes is: that on the $3+7$ *tries that matter*, the first $3+7-1$ contain 3 twos and 6 sixes in some order, and try $3+7$ contains the seventh six.

$$\mathsf P(~\uparrow~) = \dbinom{3+7-1}{3}\dfrac{2^3\,5^7}{(2+5)^{3+7}}$$

... because the probability of obtaining a two given you obtain a two or a six is:$\frac{2/36}{2/36+5/36}$

---

Moving on, the probability that you throw 3 twos before 7 sixes or 3 twelves is: that on the tries that matter you do *not* throw all the twelves *or* all the sevens before the last two. Thus by the rule of complements, and the principle of inclusion and exclusion:

$$\mathsf P(~\uparrow~) = {1-\dbinom{3+7-1}{7}\dfrac{2^3\,5^7}{(2+5)^{3+7}}\\-\dbinom{3+3-1}{3}\dfrac{2^3\,2^3}{(2+2)^{3+3}}\\+\dbinom{3+7+3-1}{7+3}\dfrac{2^3(5+2)^{7+3}}{(2+5+2)^{3+7+3}}}$$

---

And, as you see, the probability that twos win the race will be rather complicated.